# Data not loading according to iteration

Tags: javascript, rally

I’ve chosen the iteration at filter and try to load the data based on the iteration but still unable to pull the data based on the iteration but it did not show anything please help. Code I've used

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
extend: 'Rally.app.App',
componentCls: 'app',

launch: function() {

    var filters = [];
    var timeboxScope = this.getContext().getTimeboxScope();

    if(timeboxScope) {
        filters.push(timeboxScope.getQueryFilter());
    }

    this.loaddata(filters);            
},

onTimeboxScopeChange: function(newTimeboxScope) {               
    var newFilters = [];
    var updatedTimeboxScope = this.getContext().getTimeboxScope();
    if (this.grid) {
        this.grid.destroy();
    }                   
    if (updatedTimeboxScope) {
        newFilters.push(newTimeboxScope.getQueryFilter());
    }
    this.loaddata(newFilters);
},

loaddata: function(queryFilters) {
    Ext.create("Rally.data.wsapi.Store",{
       model: 'UserStory', //or defectModel
fetch: ['Tags'],
StoreConfig:{

    filters: queryFilters
},
autoLoad: true,
listeners: {
    load: function(Store, records) {
        this._loadprocessdata(records);
    },
    scope: this
}
```

});
},

```
_loadprocessdata: function(gathered){

    var tags=[];
    tags=gathered;
    var i=0;
    var interrupt=0;
    var other=0;
    var total=0;
    var percentage=0;
    for(i=0;i<tags.length;i++)
    {
        if(tags[i]==="Interrupt"){
            interrupt++;

        }
        else{
            other++;

        }


    }   

            total = other + interrupt;
            percentage = (interrupt/total)*100;

    var TagSummaryStore = Ext.create("Ext.data.Store",{
        fields:['tagName', 'other', 'total', 'percentage'],
                proxy: {
                    type: 'memory',
                    reader: {
                        type: 'json',
                        root: 'items'
                    }
                }
            });


            TagSummaryStore.add( {
                'tagName'   : tags.length,
                'others' : other,
                'Total'  : tags.length,
                'Percentage' :  percentage.toFixed()
            } );


        //Counting Tags and Visualize by Table
        var myGrid=Ext.create("Ext.grid.Panel",{
                title: 'Tag Summary',
                store: TagSummaryStore,
                columns: [
                    { text: 'Tag', dataIndex: 'tagName' },
                    { text: 'Stories', dataIndex: 'other' },
                    { text: 'Points', dataIndex: 'Total' },
                    { text: '%', dataIndex: 'Percentage' }
                ],
                renderTo: Ext.getBody()
            }
        );
        this.add(myGrid);




},
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason your filters are not being honored is because they need to be passed directly to the store, not within a StoreConfig:

```
Ext.create("Rally.data.wsapi.Store", {
   model: 'UserStory', //or defectModel
   fetch: ['Tags'],
   filters: queryFilters,

   //rest of store config here...
});
```

I also think your code where you're counting tags is a bit strange as well.  Your loop needs to be over the stories returned from the store, and then you need to actually inspect the _tagsNameArray on each Tags field.

```
var interrupt=0;
var other=0;
_.each(gathered, function(story) {
    var tagNames = _.pluck(story.get('Tags')._tagsNameArray, 'Name');
    if(_.contains(tagNames, 'Interrupt')) {
        interrupt++;
    } else {
        other++;
    }
});

var total = other + interrupt;
var percentage = (interrupt/total)*100;
```

Does that get you any further?